# Uso de Session vs Função de Consulta SQL

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e hoje eu tenho uns 10 Módulos, Atualmente eu faço o armazenamento da permissão de cada modulo em uma session  separada booleana.

O Valor de cada session recebe o nome do modulo seguido de sua permissão na inicialização no Default e deixa armazenado.

Teria muito impacto de performance eu trocar esse sistema de permissionamento por session usando uma consulta direto no banco no momento da checagem do modulo verificando suas permissões ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Depende do tipo de SGBD que irá utilizar. Se for utilizar um relacional, não terá ganho algum. Pois, tanto session quanto a maioria relacional, farão leitura em disco (com algumas ressalvas). Entretanto, se o sistema de armazenamento for específico para a performance (lei-se, "em memória"), como o Redis, Mongo, e alguns gerenciadores de cache, poderá lhe entregar um aumento de performance bem sinificativo. O link abaixo é interessante (exemplo em PHP): https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/407092-resolvido%C2%A0sess%C3%B5es-php-com-nosql/

Comment: Cara, se você não tem um problema com memória e tua session está em memória, não passe isso pro banco. Você está saindo para um lugar onde a ordem de grandeza do tempo de acesso é várias vezes superior.

Answer (score 1):

Depende, onde essa session é salva? Na memória?

Quantas vezes você faz essa checagem em um Request? Se você faz isso mais de uma vez, você vai ter perda de performance, já que agora você vai ter que ir ao banco executar a query, o banco vai processar e responder. Mesmo que o banco e aplicação estejam na mesma máquina, existe um custo de comunicação, enquanto isso, se o session estiver em memória ele é muito mais rápido de se ler.

Você deve analisar também se o sistema vai crescer. Por exemplo, se no futuro for preciso colocar a aplicação rodando em um Farm, a melhor opção seria um cache central e não várias máquinas com a mesma coisa a memória. Nesse cenário é uma boa ideia pensar em algo como Redis, já que ele é muito mais rápido que um banco de dados relacional.